# on hover drop down menu JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I was trying to turn this html into a menu using java script but i can't seem to get it working?

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="group">Friends</div>
    <div class="item">Home</div>
    <div class="item">Work</div>
    <div class="item">Family</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What javascript are you looking at using?  A framework?  Please share more details.

Comment: We need more information, what kind of menu, are you using any css, are you using anything such as jQuery?

Comment: navigation menu where it will be initially be hidden under friends and onhover home,work and family will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking about the CSS, you should be using the object:hover selector to modify for example, the property display, or opacity for the mother div (I'd use display)

```
.menu:hover {display:block;}
```

If you're using jQuery, you can use the onhover function, same principle, super basic

```
$(.menu).onhover(function(){
     this.css("display", "block")
});
```